# Un adjectif possessif peut-il renvoyer à un nom prononcé postérieurement dans la phrase?

Tags: oral, déterminants, figure-de-style

Une phrase prononcée par mon interlocutrice Mireille m'a laissé perplexe:

> **Bénédicte** et *ses* filles ont souhaité un bon anniversaire à leur mère.

La raison pour laquelle j'ai été confondu est que je savais, au même titre que Mireille, que Bénédicte n'avait pas de fille, mais des sœurs. Faisant part de ma confusion, j'ai répondu en corrigeant par la tournure qui me semblait plus logique:

> **Bénédicte** et *ses* sœurs  ont souhaité un bon anniversaire à leur mère.

Mireille renchérit en prétendant que j'avais mal interprété sa phrase, et qu'il fallait bien comprendre:

> Bénédicte et *ses* filles ont souhaité un bon anniversaire à **leur mère**.

Et que cet usage était parfaitement licite.

J'ai donc deux questions :

- Cette tournure est-elle effectivement licite ?
- Si oui, quel est le nom de la figure de style associée ?

  - Bonus, un exemple d'usage littéraire postérieur à 1850 de cette tournure.

Comment: This is perhaps more suitable for [Lingustics community](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions) as it touches on the deep grammar structure (whether possessor must be the (last) previously mentioned noun).

Comment: Est-ce une question de l'écriture inclusive ?  Et pourquoi 1850 ?  Ou s'agit-il de Mireille, Robert et Marie-Laure ?

Comment: @livresque Je souhaite,  _s'il existe_,  un exemple littéraire assez récent de cet usage.  La dase de 1850 est arbitraire. Les prênoms ont été changés.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La phrase est relativement compréhensible quand on en connait les clefs mais elle ne respecte pas la logique car Bénédicte faisant déjà partie du groupe ***ses filles***, elle ne peut pas y être ajoutée avec ***et***.
Il aurait mieux valu écrire :

> *Bénédicte et ses **autres** filles ont souhaité un bon anniversaire à leur mère.*

Cette phrase impose cependant encore un effort de compréhension qui n'est plus requis avec la phrase suggérée qui est bien plus claire :

> *Bénédicte et ses **sœurs** ont souhaité un bon anniversaire à leur mère.*

Comment: Pourrait-on dire, avec le même sens : *Bénédicte et **les** autres filles ont souhaité un bon anniversaire à leur mère.*?

Comment: @RogerVadim Oui, si toutes les filles présentes sont sœurs. "Les filles" signifie alors *the girls*, pas *the daughters*.